# Wildcards: get elements with classes that have just one character more apart from the static string

Tags: jquery

I want to use wildcards but just for those classes that have one character more apart from the static string.

This is:

Let's explain it. If I have this two elements:

```
<div class="foo_1"></div>
<div class="foo_1_other_characters"></div>
```

when using

```
$('[class^=foo_1]').html("bar");
```

I get

```
<div class="foo_1">bar</div>
<div class="foo_1_other_characters">bar</div>
```

because it is selecting both elements. But I want to select just the classes that have **ony one character more** apart from the static substring (`foo_`). That is, I would like to get just:

```
<div class="foo_1">bar</div>
```

Is this possible using jQuery?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it going to be efficient? No, not at all.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, it is fixed now

Comment: Why would you need that? Sounds like whatever you are trying to do, there is better way to do it. Maybe you have not hand on rendered HTML markup. In this case maybe your question makes sense. FYI, class attribute shouldn't be used to bring datas

Comment: @A.Wolff I have elements between the clicked element and the target element (element to select) with class names similar to the target element class.

Comment: `I have elements between the clicked element and the target element` Not sure i understand it, you should provide online sample to replicate you issue as a jsFiddle. But anyway why don't you use distinctive classes instead as e.g: `<div class="foo bar">bar</div><div class="foo quz">quz</div>`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$.fn.filter` and return a boolean to filter out just what you want.

```
$('[class]').filter(function(){
   return /\bfoo_.(\s|$)/.test(this.className);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter out those that have 1 character more apart of the string you provide:

```js
var cls="foo_";
//filter all classes that contain the substring "foo_"
$('[class*='+cls+']').filter(function(){
    //clear a flag
    var flag=false;
    //loop over each element and get its class list
    var classes=$(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
    //loop over the class collection
    classes.forEach(function(val,id){
        //check the class begins with "foo_" and not just contains it,
        //and check if the class is 1 character longer than "foo_"
        if(classes[id].substring(0,cls.length)===cls && classes[id].length==cls.length+1){
            //set flat
            flag= true;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}).html("bar");
```

```css
.green,
.red,
.blue{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
}
.green{
    border:1px solid green;
}
.red{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.blue{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo_1 green"></div>
<div class="red foo_2"></div>
<div class="foo_1_other_characters blue"></div>
```

Comment: @DavidThomas you have a point, i fixed my answer to suit your scenarios

Comment: added some css to make it easier to see the results